# Why does linear regression only function on one feature and just a straight line on the other

Tags: python, lasso-regression

So Have this code with two features, time and oil production. I run it on a lasso regression model and produces a very high rms because the lasso seams not to function on the time feauture. here is my code

```
 field_data = pd.read_csv("piper_data.csv")

feature = pd.DataFrame(field_data[['time','time','OILPRODM3']])

feature = feature.values

time = pd.DataFrame(field_data['time'])
oil = pd.DataFrame(field_data['OILPRODM3'])
wat = pd.DataFrame(field_data['INJWATVOL'])

water = field_data.INJWATVOL.tolist()
feature_train, feature_test, oil_train, oil_test = train_test_split(feature, water, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
clflasso = Lasso(alpha=.1)
clflasso.fit(feature_train, oil_train)
```

when I plot it, clearly the lasso only work on the oil production

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vyk15.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bskyV.png)

I dont really understand whats wrong

Comment: As alphas get larger, lasso regression coefficients get pushed towards zero.  Also, this might be a better question for stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Still dont get it why its okay on the other feature (oil) while not on the other (water)